# How to open a dialog after the mainWindow shows in Avalonia?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to open a dialog after mainWindow, but get error "Cannot show window with non-visible owner."

Then I got after
`InitializeComponent();`
the mainWindow is still loading.

When will the mainWindow finishe the process, where can I put the code to open a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener for the `Window.Loaded` event and place your dialog code in that listener.